# Calculating limits of areas of circle

Tags: limits

[image: Picture]

If $r$ is the radius of circle then I calculated $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ to be 
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}r^2t-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin t=\frac{1}{2}r^2(t-\sin t)$$
$$AB^2=4r^2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}= 2AC^2+2AC^2\cos(\pi-t)$$

$$g(t)=\frac{1}{2}AC^2\sin (\pi-t)-\frac{1}{2}r^2(t-\sin t )= \frac{r^2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}{1-\cos t}-\frac{1}{2}r^2(t-\sin t)$$
$$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{1}{\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}\sin t}{(1-\cos t)(t-\sin t)}-1}$$

Thus $$\ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = 0$$

Is this working correct? Intuitively we can see that as $t$ approaches $0$, line segment $AB$ becomes smaller and thus $f(t)$ approaches $0$ and $g(t)$ approaches the area $ABC$  giving a limit of $0$ which is my answer.

Comment: in line $4$, your $\frac{r^2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}{1-\cos t}$ must be $\frac{r^2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}{1+\cos t}\sin t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively:
$$\begin{align}
f(t)=&\frac{1}{2}r^2t-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin{t}=\frac{1}{2}r^2(t-\sin t). \\
AC=&r\tan{\frac{t}{2}}. \\
S_{ABC}=&\frac{1}{2}AC^2\sin{(\pi-t)}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\tan^2{\frac{t}{2}}\sin{t}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\frac{1-\cos t}{1+\cos t}\sin t. \\
g(t)=&S_{ABC}-f(t)=\frac{1}{2}r^2(\frac{1-\cos t}{1+\cos t}\sin t-t+\sin t)= \\
=&\frac{1}{2}r^2\frac{2\sin t-t(1+\cos t)}{1+\cos t}\\
\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=&\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac{(t-\sin{t})(1+\cos t)}{2\sin t-t(1+\cos t)}=2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Actually $g(t)\ne S_{ABC}-f(t)$

Comment: Actually you calculated the limit incorrectly. It is equal to 0.http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Lim+%28t-sint%29%2F%282sint-t%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: Wolfram still gives the same. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Lim+%281%2Bcost%29+%28t-sint%29%2F%28%282sint-t%29%281%2Bcost%29%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: Ohhh. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what's the problem in my method?

Answer (score 1):

I also got $f(t) = \frac{r^2}{2}(t - sint)$.

However, for $g(t)$ I obtained $$g(t) = r^2\left[sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}(t - sint)\right] = \frac{r^2}{2}\left[\frac{2sint}{cost + 1} - t\right].$$

Let me explain how I reached this conclusion for $g(t)$. First, we have to find the area of triangle $ABC$. To do this we need to find angle $A$ or angle $B$ so that we can obtain the height of $ABC$. In this case, the height of $ABC$ is the line drawn from $C$ that is perpendicular to $AB$. By [Thales Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem) we can determine that angle $A$ is equal to $\frac{t}{2}$, since we had to bisect angle $OAB$ (aka $t$) to get the equation for $f(t)$.

Now we need to recognize that the height of $ABC$ gives us two right triangles. We use that which contains point $A$, point $C$, and the point mid way between $A$ and $B$. Now we can see that $$tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) = \frac{H}{\frac{AB}{2}}$$ where $H$ is the height of $ABC$. This simplifies to $$H = rsin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$.

By definition of triangle area we get $$A_{ABC} = r^2sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$

I can edit in more steps later, but at the moment my browser is bugging out so I will submit this for now.

Thus, $$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{t - sint}{\frac{2sint}{cost + 1} - t}.$$
Notice that taking the limit of this gives $\frac{0}{0}$, so L'Hospital's rule needs to be used.

First some simplification: $$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{(t - sint)(cost + 1)}{2sint - t(cost + 1)} = \frac{tcost + t - sintcost - sint}{2sint - tcost - t}$$.

Now with L'Hospital's rule we get $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{cost - tsint + 1 - cos^2t + sin^2t - cost}{2cost - cost + tsint - 1} = \frac{0}{0}$$.

After several more instances of L'Hospital's rule we find that the limit is 2.

Credit to [farruhota](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/425072/farruhota), who realized it before I did.

Comment: Can you tell me why my $g(t)$ is wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure my g(t) is correct. I find AB using simple trigonometric Ratios then find AC by cosine rule. Found angle ACB by resolving angles for the quadrilateral ACBO. Then Used area of ACB-f(t).

Comment: What did you get for AB?

Comment: $2r\sin \frac{t}{2}$

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand now, give me a minute and I'll give you a better explanation of what to look at.

Comment: Okay, it looks like what you have for f(t)/g(t) can't be evaluated because it looks like this when you take the limit ... 1 / ((0/0) - 1)

Comment: Yes I tried L Hospital by simplifying the expression.

Comment: You can't use L'Hospitals rule on it the way you wrote it in your post. Carefully inspect the notation [written here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Notice how I used L'Hospital. I made sure that I had isolated f(t)/g(t) before applying it.

Comment: I am aware of that. I multiplied the denominator of the denominator to the whole expression. To change it to 0/0.

Comment: Okay, apologies. Give me another minute, and I'll give you some more focused feedback.

Comment: It's okay. I just want to know if my method was correct mx

Comment: Btw can you check the second answer on this post. The limit there equals 2.

Comment: Yeah, that other answer is not correct. As you noticed he used the arc length to find g(t).

Comment: No it's actually the triangle formula. Triangular area = 1/2*a*b*sin c. a=b=AC and sin c= sin(\pi-t)

Comment: So, with some algebraic manipulation I found that the way you wrote f(t)/g(t) can actually be reduced to 1/1. This can be done with the identity sin^2(t/2) = (1-cos(t))/2. So it seems that you may have made a trig error somewhere along the way when simplifying.

Comment: Well, my expression gives the correct limit 0 on wolfram. So are you sure there is an error?

Comment: Wait, haha, I made a really slight mistake. Using the trig identity in my last comment actually puts you in the position to use L'Hospital's rule (I switched the t for a 1 by accident while verifying). That expression does actually result in one. I will add an edit to my original answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Can you also check why is the second answer on this post wrong? And about the arc length, it's actually the triangular area ABC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62202/discussion-between-hwdbc-and-faiq-raees).

Comment: referring to your calculation at $f(t)/g(t)$, Alpha gives the result $2$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%5Climits%7Bt%5Cto+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bt+-+sint%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B2sint%7D%7Bcost+%2B+1%7D+-+t%7D

Comment: That's weird. Seems I may have made some sort of mistake while taking the limit of the expression I came up with. Maybe I shouldn't be so quick to jump to conclusions

Comment: I was in error saying that the second answer is invalid and that AC = rtan(t/2) is false, sorry.